# Correct way to add items to the start of list and display in Horizontal Pager. Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to add items in this way:

datesList.add(0, generatePreviousWeekItems(currentSelectedDate))

but there's incorrect behavior of Horizontal Pager

```
HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f),
            pageCount = datesList.size,
            reverseLayout = true
        ) { currentPage ->

            WeeklyViewEmptyMoveContent(
                dates = datesList[currentPage]
            )
}
```

Is there any way to do that correctly ?

Horizontal Pager doesn't work in correct way

Comment: What is the incorrect behaviour?

Comment: Provide a [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)